# mpi4py on HPC: comm.gather

Tags: python, mpi, hpc, mpi4py

My aim is to iterate through each element of a large 2D array (`data`) and do some heavy processing on each respective element. Therefore I want to use multiple MPIs to each take a portion of the array to work on. I am having the problem where I don't know how to exactly write the code to gather all the data together at the end. Here is some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from mpi4py import MPI

M = 400
N = 300
data = np.random.rand(M,N)
result_a = np.zeros((M,N))
result_b = np.zeros((M,N))

def process_function(data):
    a = data**2
    b = data**0.5
    return a,b

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
minimum = 0
maximum = int(M*N)
perrank = maximum//size

for index in range(minimum + rank*perrank, minimum + (rank+1)*perrank):
    i = int(math.floor(index/N))
    j = int(index % N)

    a,b = process_function(data[i,j])
    result_a[i,j] = a
    result_b[i,j] = b

a_gath = comm.gather(result_a, root=0)
b_gath = comm.gather(result_b, root=0)

print(np.shape(a_gath))
print('---')
print(np.shape(b_gath))
```

Unfortunately, for my real problem, when I save both `a_gath` and `b_gath` to disk (as a pickle), they only contain a single occurrence of `()` (i.e type `None`) when I re-load them. Is there something else I should be doing before/after `comm.gather`?

Here is my submission script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_rt=00:05:00
#$ -l mem=2G
#$ -l tmpfs=10G
#$ -pe mpi 5
#$ -N stack_test
#$ -notify
#$ -wd /home/user/Scratch/

module load gcc-libs
module load python3/recommended
module unload compilers mpi
module load compilers/gnu/4.9.2
module load mpi/openmpi/3.1.1/gnu-4.9.2
module load mpi4py
module list

python_infile=test.py

echo ""
echo "Running python < $python_infile ..."
echo ""
gerun python $python_infile
```

I submit this script with simply as `qsub js_test.sh`

The returned .o file for this fake example shows that, in this case 4/5 mpis contain type `None` information: Would it be in this case, that if I then saved `a_gath` and `b_gath` to disk, it would save the last mpi? which is type `None`? I would expect that after using `comm.gather`, I would have a single array of size `MxN` for variables `a_gath` and `b_gath`

```
()
---
()
()
---
()
()
---
()
(5, 400, 300)
---
(5, 400, 300)
()
---
()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Are they blank only on rank != 0?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] including instructions on how you execute it. Describe the expected and actual results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I've updated the post with more information. Hope this makes it more clear. Unfortunately I can't upload an exact example. Both my real world input data and process_function would be too complicated to replicate. Hope this is sufficient.

Comment: A more detailed check shows that yes, @GillesGouaillardet, they are only blank on rank != 0. I guess I just add a conditional statement to only write the data to disk when rank == 0?

Comment: A terminology nitpick: "I want to use multiple MPIs to each take a portion of the array to work on" - your usage seems to be clear enough from context, but I think in MPI terminology what this sentence means is that you want to break the work up across multiple ranks.  Is that right?

Comment: @AaronAltman Yep, you are correct. Sorry - still very much a novice wrt HPC

Comment: No problem.  Do you mind if I edit your post?

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: @AaronAltman ; in a similar problem, comm.gather returns a nested list and having difficulty to indexing the output data. Can you suggest how to fix the issue in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522846/how-to-concatenate-gathered-data-using-mpi4py-library-in-python/72538180#72538180

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the answer that you've found for yourself in the comments: `MPI_Gather` is a *rooted operation*: its results are not identical across all ranks, and specifically differ on the rank provided in the `root` argument.

In the case of `Gather`, your finding that rank 0 is the one that ends up with the data is exactly correct for the way you've called it (with `root=0`).

While in principle MPI supports *multiple program, multiple data* execution in which different ranks are running different code, in practice most MPI code is written in a *single program, multiple data* style, like what you've written.  Because all ranks are running the same body of code, it's up to you to check after returning from a rooted operation like `MPI_Gather` whether the rank that you're running on is the root and execute different code paths accordingly.  If you don't, then every rank is going to be executing these lines:

```
print(np.shape(a_gath))
print('---') 
print(np.shape(b_gath))
```

which, as you've noted, does not print the results you expected for `a_gath` and `b_gath` except on rank 0.

Try the following:

```
a_gath = comm.gather(result_a, root=0)
b_gath = comm.gather(result_b, root=0)

if rank == 0:
    print(np.shape(a_gath))
    print('---')
    print(np.shape(b_gath))
```